# Table population in html with complex for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

Why doesn't this work:

```
    {% for a,b,c,d,e in test1,test2,test3,test4,test5 %}
        <tr> 
          <td>{{a}}</td>
          <td>{{b}}</td>
          <td>{{c}}</td>
          <td>{{d}}</td>
          <td>{{e}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this not how this sort of task should be done?

I receive the error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ',test2,test3,test4,test5' from 'test1,test2,test3,test4,test5'
```

My view is like this:

```
def jobs(request):

test1 = range(10)
test2 = range(10)
test3 = range(10)
test4 = range(10)
test5 = range(10)

context ={

    "test1":test1,
    "test2":test2,
    "test3":test3,
    "test4":test4,
    "test5":test5,
}
return render(request,"jobs.html",context)
```

I want a table that shows job number, client, etc.. and I'm just performing tests at the moment with simple ranges to see if this works in concept. But I'm not getting it to work.

So, in production, it test1 might be equal to a list like test1 = ['Job 1','Job 2','Job 3']

Comment: What are `testN`, do they each contain five elements? What are you trying to achieve? *"is this not how this sort of task should be done?"* - what *is* this sort of task?

Comment: You appear to be trying to construct a tuple in the template which is already doing more than a template should be. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: In production, I'd hope you have an object model that actually represents the data you are trying to display, then it would just be a very simple task to iterate over a list or queryset of said model. I've deleted my answer since I'm guessing you're trying to iterate over 5 lists at once in which case you need to iterate using the `forloop.counter0`

Comment: @Sayse Your initial answer, which I saw, works but the data is flipped. Going across

Comment: @clickhere - Thats why I deleted it, I initially thought you were doing something different.

Comment: @Sayse could you explain how the forloop.counter0 might be used here? I looked at the documentation and they don't even have a single example of how it's to be used.

Comment: @clickhere - Well the forloop counter will give you an index you can look up an index from, so you could make a template tag that retrieves an object from an array at that index. But again, it is by far a lot better to just make an actual object.

Comment: @Sayse, could you give me an example of how i might modify my view/html to achieve an end result such as: https://i.imgur.com/bDeYLGa.png [ideally the test1,test2 etc.. would be lists in production]

Comment: @clickhere - I've updated my answer, just to reiterate it though **dont** use it. instead make an actual object model you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In production, I'd hope you have an object model that actually represents the data you are trying to display, then it would just be a very simple task to iterate over a list or queryset of said model.

In your current situation, you could use a mixture of custom template tags (`getrange` used below is [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1357/))

```
def index(value, arg):
    return value[arg]

{% with len=test1|length %}
{% for i in len|getrange %}
  <tr> 
      <td>{{test1|index:i}}</td>
      <td>{{test2|index:i}}</td>
      <td>{{test3|index:i}}</td>
      <td>{{test4|index:i}}</td>
      <td>{{test5|index:i}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Now I hope you can see that the above **is incredibly ugly** and should be fired into the sun at the first available opportunity.

Instead, make an actual model that represents the data.